# Command Line Editing in Windows

Tags: windows, command-prompt

This a pretty simple question, but I know that there's vi and nano for editing text files in Unix-based OS. Is there any such tool for Windows (looking specifically for Windows 10)? This would be a simple, one-line command, not a series of them (such as in Linux, I can just enter "vi somefile.txt" in order to edit it). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can download vi for windows: [VIM](http://www.vim.org/download.php)